# No plugin found for prefix 'spotless' in the current project

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

My root pom has spotless plugin -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spotless.version}</version>
 
    <configuration>
            
        <ratchetFrom>origin/main</ratchetFrom>
        <formats>
            <format>
                
                <includes>
                    <include>*.md</include>
                    <include>.gitignore</include>
                </includes>
                
                <trimTrailingWhitespace/>
                <endWithNewline/>
                <indent>
                    <tabs>true</tabs>
                    <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                </indent>
            </format>
        </formats>
            
        <java>
              
            <googleJavaFormat>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <style>AOSP</style>
                <reflowLongStrings>true</reflowLongStrings>
            </googleJavaFormat>

            <licenseHeader>
                <content>/* (C)$YEAR */</content>  
            </licenseHeader>
        </java>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My .m2/settings.xml has spotless pluginGroup added (... is organization related info) -

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>

        <mirror>
            <id>...</id>
            <mirrorOf>...</mirrorOf>
            <name>...</name>
            <url>...</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>...</id>
            <mirrorOf>...</mirrorOf>
            <url>...</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

        <pluginGroups>
            <pluginGroup>com.diffplug.spotless</pluginGroup>
        </pluginGroups>


</settings>
```

Still when i run mvn spotless:apply or mvn spotless:check, i get following error -

No plugin found for prefix 'spotless' in the current project and in the plugin groups [com.diffplug.spotless, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/sonal.chavan/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the full settings.xml file...

Comment: @khmarbaise edited the question to include that.

Comment: Hm... looks correct so far. Check to call the plugin goal with full groupId:artifactId:version:goal.

Comment: This issue can also happen in a multi-module Maven project when the command is run in the parent module instead of from inside a specific module.